# Import list(JSON) into Clickhouse

Tags: python, json, clickhouse

I can't solve this problem. I have a python list with data like:

```
results = [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
  'id': '227378',
  'self': 'https://jira.su/rest/api/2/issue/227378',
  'key': 'TUBE-77',
  'fields': {'customfield_12251': None,
   'customfield_12250': None,
   'customfield_12253': None,
   'customfield_13100': None,
   'customfield_12252': None,
   'customfield_13102': None,
   'customfield_13101': None,
   'customfield_12254': None,
   'customfield_12257': None,
   'customfield_13104': None,
   'resolution': {'self': 'https://jira.zxz.su/rest/api/2/resolution/10101',
    'id': '10101',
    'description': 'This problem is solved.',
    'name': 'DONE'},
   'customfield_13103': None}}]
```

And i need to put it into clickhouse. I use clickhouse driver and input data into the created table with this code:

```
ch_client.execute(f'SET input_format_skip_unknown_fields=1;')
ch_client.execute(f'INSERT INTO {table} FORMAT JSONEachRow', results)
```

Field **key** inserts without problems, but if i want to insert data from **customfield_12251** or **description** returns **KeyError: 'fields:customfield_12251'**.
I don't understand how i must name fields in the clickhouse table...

Comment: What is the schema of your ClickHouse table?

Comment: Table created with engine MergeTree. Now it has field key (string) and other fields i tried to add during the data insert and checked the result

Comment: You need to explicitly specific the data type for each column and columns cannot be nested, unless you are using the JSON data type for the column (such as a column `fields JSON`

Comment: could you provide the schema of table?